# How to set default value in request xml of SOAPUI other than '?'

Tags: wsdl, soapui

When I load an WSDL file, the values for elements is by default appeared as follows:

```
           <mod:country>?</mod:country>
           <mod:variant>?</mod:variant>
           <mod:language>?</mod:language>
```

Don't want this ? want to set another default value to be appeared as over there whenever I load any WSDL file in SOAPUI.

As I want to to load with with empty values for elements as :

```
           <mod:country></mod:country>
           <mod:variant></mod:variant>
           <mod:language></mod:language>
```

Can any one Please help me to set the default value for SOAPUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to change the default value other than `?`. However, it will not generate empty elements in the request. Instead, it will have some example values generated by SoapUI.

All you need to do is to navigate

`Menu -> File -> Preferences -> WSDL Settings ->` then check the box for `Sample Values [] Generates example values in requests when creating from schema`.

Save the preferences.

Now create a request to see if the request elements contains example values.

For more details, please see the [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/soapui-interface/preferences-and-settings.html).

Comment: Thank you for this..:) INstead of generating sample values can we set it as empty??

Comment: @user3363047, It is already mentioned in the answer that it is not possible for empty. If you think this is helpful, then [accept answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)